# Null reference,fiz uma verificacao antes de inserir os valores e o erro continua

Tags: c#

Estou tendo este erro quando no meu programa temos duas classes com métodos referenciados.

> System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
>             HResult=-2147467261
>             Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>             Source=Programacao em Linguagens Comerciais
>             StackTrace:
>                  at Programacao_em_Linguagens_Comerciais.FormCadastroUsuario.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\users\lucas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Programacao em Linguagens Comerciais\Programacao em Linguagens Comerciais\Tela_Cadastro_Usuario.cs:line 63
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>                  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>                  at Programacao_em_Linguagens_Comerciais.Program.Main() in d:\users\lucas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Programacao em Linguagens Comerciais\Programacao em Linguagens Comerciais\Program.cs:line 19
>                  at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>                  at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>                  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>                  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>                  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>                  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>             InnerException:

O erro ocorre quando estou tentando gravar no banco de dados o campo *Usuario.login.login*, ele passa pela parte que grava *Usuario.nome* e quando chega no que seria *Usuario.login.login* ele da este erro, saberiam me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado ?O código é auto incrementado no banco de dados.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    public class Login
    {
        public Login() { }
        public String login;
        public String senha;
        public bool tipo; 
    }
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    class Usuario
    {
        public Usuario() { }
        public int codigo;
        public String nome;
        public Login login;       
    }
```

A parte que tem o erro, nela eu faço a verificação com o **IF** para ver se algum dos campos não esta em branco. Não sei porquê ela continua retornando essa mensagem de erro se nunca vai acontecer o `if` se algum dos campos estiver vazio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Programacao_em_Linguagens_Comerciais
{
    public partial class FormCadastroUsuario : Form
    {
        public FormCadastroUsuario()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void FormCadastroUsuario_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        public void textBox5_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Usuario Entrada = new Usuario();
            new CadastroUsuarioService().Gravar(Entrada);
                if (TXTCadastroUsuarioNome.Text != "" && TXTCadastroUsuarioLogin.Text != "" && TXTCadastroUsuarioSenha.Text != "")
                {
                    Entrada.nome = TXTCadastroUsuarioNome.Text;
                    Entrada.login.login = TXTCadastroUsuarioLogin.Text;
                    Entrada.login.senha = TXTCadastroUsuarioSenha.Text;
                    MessageBox.Show("usuario cadastrado.");
                } 
           // MessageBox.Show("Autenticacao efetuada com sucesso");
           // this.Hide();
            //FormCadastroUsuario Tela = new FormCadastroUsuario();
            //Tela.Visible = true;   
          //  MessageBox.Show("Falha na autenticacao");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Programacao_em_Linguagens_Comerciais
{
    class CadastroUsuarioService
    {
        public void Gravar(Usuario usuario)
        {
            new CadastroUsuarioDAO().Gravar(usuario);
        }
    }
}
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Programacao_em_Linguagens_Comerciais
{
    class CadastroUsuarioDAO
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        private String connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=DB_Atps_Prog_Ling_Comerc;Uid=Lucas;Pwd=123;";
        public CadastroUsuarioDAO()
        {
            OpenCon();
        }
        public void OpenCon()
        {
            if (conn == null)
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            }
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
        }
        public void CloseCon()
        {
            if (conn != null && conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        public void Gravar(Usuario usuario)
        {
            try
            {
                if (usuario.nome != "" && usuario.login.login != "" && usuario.login.senha != "")
                {
                    String comandoMysql = "insert into Usuario(nome,login,senha)"
       + "values ('" + usuario.nome + "','" + usuario.login.login + "','" + usuario.login.senha + "')";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(comandoMysql, conn);
                    //   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você instancia um usuário, mas não o Login do usuário, então ele é nulo.

Comment: tentei procurar na internet e nao achei como fazer algo parecido com isso que vce falou, eu ja havia procurado mas eu nao sei explicar o que eh e nem usar o termo para se fazer isso, poderia me mostrar como ? nao precisa ser em cima do meu codigo pode fazer um exemplo com ClasseA.ClasseB.Atributo1

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa instanciar um login e colocá-lo dentro de usuário, uma boa maneira de fazer isso seria utilizando o construtor de usuário:

```
public Usuario(Login login) {
    this.login = login;
}
```

Dessa maneira, o login passaria a existir, pois você o instanciaria e conseguiria acessá-lo da maneira que desejas.

```
Usuario entrada = new Usuario(new Login());
entrada.nome = TXTCadastroUsuarioNome.Text;
entrada.login.login = TXTCadastroUsuarioLogin.Text;
entrada.login.senha = TXTCadastroUsuarioSenha.Text;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, estou tentando se eu conseguir eu aviso, valeu ! !

Comment: mds kra vc eh 1 god! consegui sim, obrigado pela resposta vlws ! :D